# The Calendar Widget ain't working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

Inside Calendar in this property `onDateSelected` I'm passing date. day in function. The calendar is throwing an error that int isn't the subtype of DateTime, but if I pass the date(which is of DateTime) the calendar isn't working. It's not dynamic, it just reloads whenever I click on it.

```
onDateSelected: (date) {
                    return _handleData(date);
                  },
```

**OR**

```
onDateSelected: (date) {
                    return _handleData(date.day);
                  },
```

```
DateTime? selectedDay;
void _handleData(date) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDay = date;
        // selectedEvent = events[selectedDay] ?? [];
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think your selectedDay datatype is int that's why you getting error that int isn't the subtype of DateTime

```
DateTime? selectedDay = DateTime.now();

 //Here is Calendar widget
Calendar(
        initialDate: selectedDay,
        events: const {},
        startOnMonday: true,
        isExpandable: true,
        eventDoneColor: Colors.green,
        selectedColor: Colors.pink,
        todayColor: Colors.blue,
        eventColor: Colors.grey,
        onDateSelected: (date) {
          _handleNewDate(date);
        },
      ),

void _handleNewDate(date) {
 setState(() {
   selectedDay = date;
   // selectedEvent = events[selectedDay] ?? [];
   print(selectedDay);
 });
}
```

Comment: it's of DateTime

Comment: Which calendar library are you using or using default?

Comment: flutter_clean_calendar

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check I think it is help you

Comment: It's solved not getting error.

Comment: but i don't know why the date is showing more than two(or more) events instead of one. It's just repeating.

Comment: I think you are misplaced in event section in map please check in your event section.